# hazelcast : return leader name / address in hazelcast cluster

Tags: java, java-8, java-7, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

how do i get leader in a cluster of nodes

I can get a boolean value comparing against local like below..

```
  public boolean isLeader() {

// Get all the Hazelcast instances in the current JVM.
// In case of carbon server this is always either one 
// or zero.
Iterator<HazelcastInstance> iter
                    = Hazelcast.getAllHazelcastInstances().iterator();

if (iter.hasNext()) { // cluster mode 
    HazelcastInstance instance = iter.next();
    return instance.getCluster().getMembers().iterator().next().localMember();
} else {
    return true; // standalone mode
 }
}
```

Here i can use this boolean funtion to check for LEADER 
But incase if local is not the oldest / leader , then i want to get the leader host to do some opearation

```
if(isLeader) {
 // do something 
} else {
// getLeaderHost(); 
// do something else 
}
```

Comment: Mind sharing what operation you are planning to make the leader do?  You have no control over cluster members for how they distribute data across the cluster. The only thing you can do is ExecutorService operation and even then I can not think of a scenario to know the master of the cluster in order to perform the executor operation.

Comment: Is there a question? Or do you just want confirmation of your solution? Does your code work?